# Cant have to displays running on li

Tags: html, css

So I have a Li that runs like follows to show the content
https://i.cloudup.com/wIVZQfesOU.png

I need to make the li's Display to take up the whole box,
whilst at the same time it needs to display to stick to the right
rather than running downwards.

```
.navbar                     {width: 100%;height: 50px;background: #0088df}

ul                          {margin: none;padding-left: 20px}
li                          {height: 100%;width: 150px;line-height: 50px;display: block;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;text-transform: uppercase;}
li:hover, li a:hover        {background: #fff;color: #000;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
li{
height: 100%;
width: 150px;
line-height: 50px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Works wonderfull, will set as answer when 11 minutes pass. Thanks :D